# Convert B5 to A4

Tags: formatting, geometry

For my thesis I am trying to convert my file from B5 to A4 without incurring incredible errors.

Having said that, having as a template the one posted below (and attached), which parts should I change?

The typographic rules I would like to follow are:

- A4 format
- body 12
- justified text
- margins 3 cm (all)
- interline 1.5

```latex
\documentclass[11pt, b5paper, twoside, openright]{book}
%\usepackage[cam,a4,center,pdflatex]{crop}
\usepackage[b5,center,pdflatex]{crop}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx, epsfig}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{captcont}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\makeindex
%
%pacchetti creati da me
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,italian=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesis.bib}
\usepackage{tocbibind} %inserisce l'indice analitico e quello di tabelle e figure nell'indice.
%\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry} %setta i margini
%
%pacchetti creti da me per l'elenco delle formule
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Elenco delle equazioni}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\setlength{\cftbeforemyequationsskip}{1pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\textsl{ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\textsl{ #1}}{}} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\headheight}{14pt}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% jpg images paths 
\newcommand{\jpgfigspath}{./figures_jpg/}
% png images paths 
\newcommand{\pngfigspath}{./figures_png/}
%
%
\begin{document}
%
%% COPERTINA
\frontmatter
\input{copertina.tex}
\newpage
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%\input{copyright.tex}
%\newpage
%
%% SOMMARIO
\input{sommario.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% RICONOSCIMENTI
\input{riconoscimenti.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% INDICE
\tableofcontents
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%%ELENCO DELLE FIGURE
\listoffigures
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%%ELENCO DELLE TABELLE
\listoftables
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%%ELENCO DELLE FORMULE
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Elenco delle equazioni}
\listofmyequations
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% PRIMO CAPITOLO
\mainmatter
\input{./chapters/1energia.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% SECONDO CAPITOLO
\input{./chapters/2tropo.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% TERZO CAPITOLO
\input{./chapters/3cfd.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
% 11QUARTO CAPITOLO
\input{./chapters/4risultati.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%% CONCLUSIONI 
\input{./chapters/conclusioni.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
\backmatter
%
\appendix
\input{appendice.tex}
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% BIBLIOGRAFIA originale
%\bibliographystyle{acm}
%\bibliography{thesis}
%\backmatter
%
%% BIBLIOGRAFIA nuova
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
%% INDICE DEI SOGGETTI
\printindex    
\clearpage{\pagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need a4 in crop, not b5. See https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5257.

Comment: don't load `epsfig` in any document written in the last 25 years, but these package calls are inconsistent `\usepackage[b5,center,pdflatex]{crop}  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx, epsfig}`  The first you are forcing `pdflatex` so it only works with pdflatex and not with latex, and the second you are forcing `dvips` so it only works with latex and not pdflatex. It is always better not to specify the back end driver option at all and let latex automatically set it to the right thing.

Comment: (i) it is sufficient to load each package only ones, (ii) ˙xcolor` is supersede of the `color` package, so later is no need to load, (iii) ˙hyperref` package should be load the last in preamble (with rare exception, which is not present in your preamble), (iv) for define page layout is very handy package `geometry`), (v)  for test of the desired page layout you make small document with some dummy test, for example by use `lipsum` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- as starting point, replace first five lines in your document example with

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}  % changed
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            margin=30mm,
            ]{geometry}                         % new
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{setspace}                           % new
\onehalfspace                                   % new
```

- other part of preamble you can left as it is, however, I suggest you that rethink if you really need alt those packages
- it is good if the packages are grouped according to their purpose (for example: group of packages for math, etc)
- also consider suggestion givens in comments below your question.

An Example of MWE, Which show you new pages size of your book is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openright]{book}  % changed
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            margin=30mm,
            ]{geometry}                         % new
\usepackage{graphicx}                           % changed
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{setspace}                           % new
\onehalfspace                                   %

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

In above MWE (Minimal Working Example) I didn't bother with page headers and footers. If you will problems with them, please ask new question.

[image]